# Setting Confidence Threshold in Speech To Text [Watson ]

Tags: speech-recognition, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I've searched high and low in the documentation but still unclear how to set the confidence threshold for the Watson Speech To text API.

Threshold is mentioned near the bottom here but no mention of how to actually set it when making the request.

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-grammarUnderstand

Is this done somewhere in the request?

Answer (score 1):

see the API reference: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text

> **word_alternatives_threshold**
>
> A confidence value that is the lower bound for identifying a hypothesis as a possible word alternative (also known as "Confusion Networks"). An alternative word is considered if its confidence is greater than or equal to the threshold. Specify a probability between 0.0 and 1.0. No alternative words are computed if you omit the parameter. See Word alternatives.